# Reachability false positive problems

Tags: objective-c, reachability

I am trying to perform a selector from the class A in the AppDelegate.

I set up an alert which prompts the user, soon after they buy the app, to download all contents at once and cache them to read them later.

I have the exact thing in the class A and it's working really good.

Now, when I try to do it at first launch, reachability says I'm offline while I'm actually online.

Contents can be only downloaded over WiFi and not 3G (data plan saving), but, even if I'm in my own WiFi network, it says I'm offline.

I'm using the following code in the App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"mainLaunch"]){
    [self performSelector:@selector(askForDownloadContentsAtFirstStart) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"mainLaunch"];


    //...
    }


-(void)askForDownloadContentsAtFirstStart{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download contents" message:@"blahblahblah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil]autorelease];
    [alert show];
}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }else{
        aVc = [[AViewController alloc]init];
        [aVc performSelector:@selector(offlineDownload:)];
    }
}
```

And the following one in my aVc:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(offlineDownload:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
}

    - (IBAction)offlineDownload:(id)sender{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Blahblahblah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil]autorelease];
        [alert show];
    }


    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if (buttonIndex == 0){
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
            switch (internetStatus) {
                case NotReachable:
                {
                   NSLog(@"Offline");
                }
                case (ReachableViaWWAN):
                {
                    NSLog(@"3G");
                }
                case (ReachableViaWiFi):{
                    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:key_Window animated:YES]retain];
                    HUD.delegate = self;
                    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Connecting",@"Connecting...");
                    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"plistUrl",@"")];
                    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
                    [request addValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
                    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                    [connection start];
                    [connection release];
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

This issue has happened again but I solved it by retaining internetReachable. Now, it seems that doesn't work!

Any idea?

Comment: This is a duplicate of countless reachability questions.  Reachability does not tell you whether you have internet access or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an observer for the `kReachabilityChangedNotification` notification like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

And then start the notifier:

```
[[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] startNotifier];
```

And in your notification listener you can test if wifi is available:

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(netStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {
        // wifi available
        [self askForDownloadContentsAtFirstStart];
    }
}
```

Comment: in your app delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you would add the observer and start the notifier.

Comment: Okay so I guessed right. But how can it be combined with the alertView delegate method? I mean, I have to execute this task ONLY if the user taps on "YES" and ONLY over WiFi.

Comment: I updated my code to show how... you just have to show the alert view once you know that the wifi is available.

Comment: Uhm, it keeps telling me I'm offline EVEN if i put a NSLog in reachabilityChanged: to see if there is a WiFi. That's weird, I suppose the problem is in the class then.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the most recent version of reachability?

Comment: I am using Reachability v.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the Reachability is guaranteed to be correct as soon as the app starts up.  Our solution was to monitor the notifications, wait until it reported a successful connection, and then handle things from there.

Our apps also call *startNotifier* on *internetReachable* and then note the reachability in the *-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)theNotification* callback.  We do this in a manager class that we can then check for the current reachability, and it can also send out notifications to the rest of the app (if necessary) when the reachability changes.

Comment: I already have something that, on startup, works nicely (it downloads automatically new content if the user activated the option). I just don't get why it doesn't work now. The funny thing is that the first reachability (for the automatic download) reports the connection as active, while the second one reports an offline status. Oh, so you made a sort of global class, right?

Comment: Yes, it basically wraps the reachability for use in the rest of the app as something that can be queried and send out more meaningful notifications.  It also keeps our app's interaction with the Reachability code limited to a single class should we ever want to swap it out.